# Morse to English/English to Morse Converter

Tags: java, arrays, string, replace, morse-code

Hi I'm trying to make a java program that translates English to Morse and vice versa. 
Basically I'm having trouble getting everything to become compatible.. and how to use the replace all method to get all the varaiubles entered to be replaced by those corresponding i the index of Morse. I'm not trying to shortcut this much..I've really tried hard and want to get this done with. thank you so much!

```
    import java.util.Scanner;

       public class ProjMorse
     {
    public static void main( String [] args )
    {
       Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
      String [] alpha =  {"a",b","c","d","e","f","g","h","i","j","k","l","m","n","o","p","q","r","s","t","u","v","w","x","y","z","1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","0"," "};
    String [] dottie = {".-", "-...", "-.-.", "-..", "-..", ".", "..-.", "--.", "....", "..", ".---", "-.-", ".-..", "--", "-.", "---", ".--.", "--.-", ".-.", "...", "-", "..-", "...-", ".--", "-..-", "-.--", "--..", "-----", ".----", "..---", "...--", "....-", ".....", "-....", "--...", "---..", "----.", "-----", "|"};
    System.out.println("To convert from English to Morse enter English");
String ans = input.nextLine();
    if(ans.equals("English"))
    {
  System.out.println( "Please enter the text you would like to convert to Morse Code: ");
      String English = input.nextLine();
  char[] translates = (English.toLowerCase()).toCharArray();

  for (int i = 0; i < alpha.length; i++)
  {
        String s  = translates[i].replaceAll('i', (dottie[i]));
  }
  String s = new String(dottie[i]);
      System.out.println(s);
    }
    else
    {
  System.out.println( "Please enter the text you would like to convert to English (separate words with '|'):");
  String code = input.nextLine();
  String[] translates = code.split("[|]", 0);

  for (int j = 0; j < dottie.length; j++)
  {
    alpha[j] = String.valueOf(translates[j]);
  }
  String s = new String(alpha[j]);
  System.out.println(s);
}
    }
  }
```

Comment: 1) Use a consistent and logical indent for code blocks.  The indentation of the code is intended to help people understand the program flow. 2) Please don't forget to add a '?' to questions!  Some people do a search in the page for '?' and if none exists in the 'question' go directly to the next (actual) question in line.  3) There is no need to add the major tag in the title.

Comment: Doing everything in one method is always a bad idea.  Methods should do only one thing and do it well. Generally you should try to keep them below 30~ lines (less than a screen full)

Comment: Why would you try to do this in a single method, unless it is homework ?

Comment: And what is your question???

Comment: What happens and what do you expect to happen? What is the problem?

Comment: `but if it's not possible to do so without using other methods` `translates[i].replaceAll` `replaceAll` is a method. This code is wrong? What you want?

Comment: Well, basically I'm getting a few errors and I'm not sure how to fix them..

Comment: I've tried replaceAll but it wasn't reading it.. it was giving me errors with incompatible types and such

Comment: BTW `split` uses regex and `|` is regex metacharacter. Don't forget to escape it like `split("\\|")` or `split("[|]")`.

Comment: Also try using indentations in your code. It helps to see scope of variables.

Comment: I thought I wouldn't need that because it's only one character?

Comment: Why does dotties have 2 elements more than alpha?

Comment: Is this a sufficient question now?

Comment: @axiopisty it does? I'm pretty sure they're equal in length...

Comment: You might want to double check that. There are 37 in alpha and 39 in dotties.

Comment: gahh yeah I counted. okay thank you(:

Comment: You're missing a `"` in your `String [] alpha` value, using more internal whitespace (such as `"a", "b", "c"` instead of `"a","b","c") makes things like that easier to spot with a Mark-1 eyeball.

Comment: @muistooshort are you sure? I double checked and it was fine...
Ahh I see it now, must have been a copy and paste error as it's fine on my program. Thank you(:

Answer (score 1):

```
  for (int i = 0; i < alpha.length; i++)
  {
        String s  = translates[i].replaceAll('i', (dottie[i]));
  }
```

This wont work, what you are trying to do is step through each character of the string to be translated (which you have converted to a char array) and do a `replaceAll` instances of the letter 'i' with the relative index in the morse code alphabet.  `replaceAll` is a method of the String class, this wont work.

If you hadn't converted it to a char array you could do a `replaceAll` on the plaintext string containing chars in `alpha` with each item in `dottie`.

```
 int characterIndex = 0;
 for (char c : alpha)
 {
   plaintextString.replaceAll(c, dottie[characterIndex]);
   characterIndex++;
 }
```

**Additionally...**

First, if you are asking a question, it should contain a question, with question mark and all.  So that we know what we're answering.  If you have an error you need to include what error that is.  You'll need to format your code better as well, that was really hard to read...

Now, notes on your code, don't try and do everything in one method, it's ugly and hard to read and debug.  Methods should do one thing (not multiple things like getting user input, translating, output) and do it well.  The reason behind this is so that methods purpose can be understood better and faster if you can read the whole thing on one screen.

Also, variables should start with a lower case letter, so this can be confusing:-

```
String English = input.nextLine();
```

Comment: Yeah, I know it doesn't work..how would I fix it?

Comment: Okay, could I do the same for morse? with string c : dottie?

Comment: yes, that should work

Comment: Just out of curiosity, why use c? I've seen that before and I know it doesn't matter what you use, but why c? Thank you again! 
Also, would there be no need for char[] translates = (english.toLowerCase()) now that I'm using plaintextString? And my output would be dottie[characterIndex], correct? Happy New Year!

Comment: Yea that should work.  c Was just a random letter selection.

Comment: ...why did you unaccepted the answer btw?

Comment: ...it didn't work. :/

Comment: what not? what was wrong

Comment: Method replace all cannot be applied to given types, incompatible types, etc

Comment: ah, I see.  It may be the `char` argument in `replaceAll`, change it to a `String`

Comment: for what, toEnglish? I tried that..

Comment: the `c` in `plaintextString.replaceAll(c, dottie[characterIndex]);` is a `char` but that argument needs to be a `String`

Comment: like translates[stringIndex].replaceAll(a, dottie[stringIndex])
would that work? I tried it that way and it failed to compile..

Comment: I've tried all the paintexString stuff and it simply doesn't work.. I may be doing it wrong, but it's not working..